# Select values from pandas dataframe at intervals

Tags: python, list, pandas

I'm trying to run a calculation that requires a number of inputs (10) at one time from a list of a lot (hundreds) of inputs.

I have a dataframe of random values:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=240))
```

I want to take the first 10 values and stick them in a list, then run the calculation. Then I want to take the next 10 values from the dataframe and add those to a new list and run that calculation again.

How do you do this in Pandas?

Comment: Do you want to create a df out of the calculated values?

Comment: IIUC the you could do `for rows in df.iloc[::10]: #do stuff with rows`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use a `generator`:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=240))

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

c = chunks(s.tolist(), 10)

print(next(c))
[198, 854, 363, 818, 664, 983, 110, 333, 428, 801]

print(next(c))
[711, 973, 938, 518, 765, 739, 59, 546, 377, 834]
```

As discussion has moved to interesting performance aspects, here's how the following versions that differ by `Series` or `list` input compare. Providing `pd.Series.tolist()` as input to the `generator` expression works reasonably well:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=200000))

def chunks_gen_tolist(s):
    c = chunks(s.tolist(), 10)
    for row in c:
        next(c)

%timeit chunks_gen_tolist(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.2 ms per loop
```

And not much different from using a `list` input instead:

```
def chunks_gen_l(s):
    l = s.tolist()
    c = chunks(l, 10)
    for row in c:
        next(c)

%timeit chunks_gen_l2()
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop
```

On @Padraic Cunningham's comment: my understanding is that memory for `s` is allocated when it is first created, whereas the `chunk` function returns a `generator` that produces the `slices` on each call to `yield()` via `next()`.

I'm getting slightly lower performance for the `itertools.islice` based version:

```
from itertools import islice
def n_sli(s,n):
    it = s.__iter__()
    for sli in iter(lambda:list(islice(it, n)), []):
       yield sli   

def sli(s):
    for sli in n_sli(s, 10):
        pass

% timeit sli(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.8 ms per loop
```

Looks like for your purposes you now have several viable options at your disposal.

Comment: You are reading all the data at once with with `s.tolist()` so the generator is not really doing anything to avoid reading all the data at once

Comment: Updated my answer to address your comment - please let me know what you think.

Comment: `s.__iter__()` does not read any of the data into memory, `tolist()` creates a full list of all the data in memory, the islice method only stores an n length  list at a time in memory. Also `for row in c` already gets each chunk, calling `next(c)` means you get two at a time and it would error for uneven length s or slices.  For larger data sizes you slice size would likely increase , as it does the islice will match or outperform the manual slicing

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pull the values lazily without creating a full list first which `tolist()` will do:

```
from itertools import islice

s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=240))

def n_sli(s,n):
    it = s.__iter__()
    for sli in iter(lambda:list(islice(it, n)), []):
       yield sli

for sli in n_sli(s, 10):
    print(sli)
```

You can see this performs as well as reading all the data as suggested in other answer without ever storing more than `n` vals in memory:

```
In [30]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=200000))

In [31]: %%timeit
for r in n_sli(s, 1000):
    pass
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.82 ms per loop

In [32]: %%timeit
for r in chunks(s, 1000):
    pass
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.85 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could get your chunks with for loop and `tolist` method (if you really need a list but not part of Pandas Series):

```
chunks = [s.tolist()[i:i+10] for i in range(0, s.size, 10)]

In [187]: chunks
Out[187]: 
[[555, 262, 516, 482, 940, 851, 889, 896, 597, 240],
 [530, 300, 464, 908, 565, 219, 421, 399, 64, 433],
 [488, 998, 422, 872, 612, 223, 726, 979, 886, 955],
 [164, 534, 61, 918, 225, 851, 290, 170, 815, 415],
 [755, 187, 695, 479, 836, 848, 647, 568, 135, 808],
 [442, 284, 228, 183, 506, 813, 316, 141, 267, 374],
 [640, 63, 875, 191, 98, 164, 678, 399, 164, 177],
 [725, 960, 403, 929, 597, 20, 773, 890, 677, 992],
 [658, 267, 754, 945, 506, 314, 803, 738, 583, 260],
 [153, 74, 821, 386, 451, 520, 490, 180, 602, 609],
 [473, 515, 957, 775, 138, 721, 454, 867, 990, 202],
 [934, 186, 754, 238, 486, 43, 16, 623, 338, 734],
 [825, 334, 430, 490, 571, 676, 164, 202, 391, 992],
 [909, 965, 192, 905, 792, 805, 39, 77, 600, 260],
 [577, 313, 127, 145, 250, 248, 756, 374, 56, 418],
 [595, 616, 94, 215, 758, 675, 131, 616, 501, 650],
 [327, 604, 731, 67, 543, 439, 378, 137, 79, 516],
 [615, 982, 721, 77, 851, 839, 971, 539, 535, 433],
 [631, 948, 597, 178, 686, 448, 197, 853, 713, 98],
 [206, 661, 83, 472, 694, 659, 809, 99, 916, 390],
 [957, 200, 856, 626, 588, 549, 288, 830, 257, 389],
 [793, 475, 757, 638, 469, 186, 103, 239, 734, 896],
 [988, 676, 993, 301, 785, 584, 8, 310, 388, 833],
 [42, 319, 62, 333, 115, 275, 431, 127, 420, 610]]

In [189]: chunks[0]
Out[189]: [555, 262, 516, 482, 940, 851, 889, 896, 597, 240]
```

**EDIT**

For you it's better to use @Stefan's answer because it's faster. Although it's interesting that with `s.iloc[i:i+10].tolist()` works slower than `s.tolist()[i:i+10]`. Some benchmarking:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def stefan(s):
    c = chunks(s.tolist(), 10)
    for row in c:
        pass

In [286]: %timeit stefan(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.3 µs per loop

In [287]: %timeit [s.tolist()[i:i+10] for i in range(0, s.size, 10)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 562 µs per loop

In [288]: %timeit [s.iloc[i:i+10].tolist() for i in range(0, s.size, 10)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop
```

**EDIT2**

As @PadraicCunningham pointed out in the comment it's better to assign `s.tolist()` to some list and then use for loop:

```
In [12]: %timeit [s.tolist()[i:i+10] for i in range(0, s.size, 10)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 415 µs per loop

In [14]: %%timeit
    s_list = s.tolist()
    [s_list[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(s_list), 10)]
    ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: `s.tolist()` is creating a full list of all the values on every iteration

Comment: But it's still faster than `s.iloc[i:i+10].tolist()`. Although generator is better to use for that purpose

Comment: yes but why would you not call it once and just store it outside the list comp? if you had a million values then you create a list if 1 million values every time you want just `n` of those